# Authorize.net direct post update from md5 to signature sha

Tags: magento-1.9

Recently i have seen 2 blogs , one is http://www.programmingsimplified.in/2019/03/how-to-update-magento-authorizenet.html

& other is official: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024368392-Update-Authorize-Net-Direct-Post-from-MD5-to-SHA-512

In magento , there is two payment method of authorize (**1. Authorize.net direct post** and **2. authorize.net**)

I have my magento store which uses 2nd method Authorize.net since last two years. but i am not using authorize.net direct post.

My question is that, Should i update the authorize.net using patch ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use Authorize.net direct post you no need to apply the patch since Authorize.net doesn't use MD5 hash. The patch affects only Authorize.net direct post adding a signature key field in the backend where as Authorize.net is unaltered by this patch.

Comment: means, there is no problem occur in payment processing in authorize.net ?

Comment: Yes, you no need to apply the patch and you will not face any problems with existing payment method